# How to view Lambda results in CloudWatch Event Logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I was following [Tutorial: Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events - Amazon CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) on how to Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events.

It all makes sense and work as expected, but in my logs I cannot find the results of the lambda calls, but only custom logs that were written in the code and I can see the incoming payloads.

Are results supposed to show or do I specifically need to Log them in my code?

Comment: Does the lambda role have permission to post logs to CloudWatch?

Comment: yes. logs are being posted to CloudWatch.

Comment: I don't believe lambda itself logs the response. You can log them in your code and it will show up on CWLogs

Answer (score 0):

If lambda has got these IAM permissions it will show the custom loggers as well as default AWS invocation/error logs

"logs:CreateLogGroup",
"logs:CreateLogStream",
"logs:PutLogEvents"